# Creating conditional stacked labeling in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I found a code example for what I'm looking to accomplish at [Creating conditional stacked labeling in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/333187/115)

I want to display filter quantity and sizes for a school district per building in a stacked format, but not display a line if there is a null value in the field. I could use another value besides null if necessary. These are currently all text fields.

```
def FindLabel ([UNITID],  [SIZE1],  [QTY1],  [SIZE2],  [QTY2],  [SIZE3],  [QTY3],  [SIZE4],  [QTY4]):
if [QTY3] != "" and [SIZE4] == 'Null':
    return [UNITID] + "\n" + [QTY1] + " (" + [SIZE1] + ")" + "\n" + [QTY2] + " (" + [SIZE2] + ")" + "\n" + [QTY3] + " (" + [SIZE3] + ")"
elif [QTY2] != "" and [SIZE3] == 'Null':
    return [UNITID] + "\n" + [QTY1] + " (" + [SIZE1] + ")" + "\n" + [QTY2] + " (" + [SIZE2] + ")"
elif [QTY1] != "" and [SIZE2] == 'Null':
    return [UNITID] + "\n" + [QTY1] + " (" + [SIZE1] + ")"
else:
    return [UNITID] + "\n" + [QTY1] + " (" + [SIZE1] + ")" + "\n" + [QTY2] + " (" + [SIZE2] + ")" + "\n" + [QTY3] + " (" + [SIZE3] + ")" + "\n" + [QTY4] + " (" + [SIZE4] + ")"
```

[image: Error Report]

Answer (score 1):

You probably have null values in one or more fields (not to be confused with a the literal string value of `"Null"`) which are getting passed through as `None`, a special Python type which can't be concatenated to strings in that way.

You're only currently checking for empty strings, but a more generic way to check for either would be to do simply `if [field]`, since using a string in a boolean condition will only evaluate to `False` when it's empty.

`bool("") == False` and `bool(None) == False`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a few examples elsewhere, and came up with this working solution. All I want to do now is bold and underline the UNITID.

I'm posting the code here for anyone else who wants an easy solution.

```
    def FindLabel ( [UNITID], [QTY1], [SIZE1], [QTY2], [SIZE2], [QTY3], [SIZE3], [QTY4], [SIZE4] ):  
  if [UNITID] and [QTY1] and [SIZE1] and [QTY2] and [SIZE2] and [QTY3] and [SIZE3] and [QTY4] and [SIZE4]:  
      return [UNITID] + '\r' + [QTY1] + "x " + [SIZE1] + '\r' + [QTY2] + "x " + [SIZE2] + '\r' + [QTY3] + "x " + [SIZE3] + '\r' + [QTY4] + "x " + [SIZE4] 
  elif [UNITID] and [QTY1] and [SIZE1] and [QTY2] and [SIZE2] and [QTY3] and [SIZE3]:  
      return [UNITID] + '\r' + [QTY1] + "x " + [SIZE1] + '\r' + [QTY2] + "x " + [SIZE2] + '\r' + [QTY3] + "x " + [SIZE3]
  elif [UNITID] and [QTY1] and [SIZE1] and [QTY2] and [SIZE2]:  
      return [UNITID] + '\r' + [QTY1] + "x " + [SIZE1] + '\r' + [QTY2] + "x " + [SIZE2]
  elif [UNITID] and [QTY1] and [SIZE1]:  
      return [UNITID] + '\r' + [QTY1] + "x " + [SIZE1]
```